# Trying to pass VLAN between Force10 S25 switches

Tags: switch, vlan, force10

I have a Force10 S25 switch in each of my two buildings.  One building uses VLAN 200 to work with 10.2.0.0 /16 traffic, the other building uses VLAN 400 for 10.4.0.0 /16 traffic.  Our wireless guest network in the VLAN 200 building is segmented off onto VLAN 20 on the network 172.16.20.0 /23.

I am trying to add this VLAN to the Force10 switches in order to allow VLAN 20 to pass guest network traffic from the VLAN 400 building as well, since our ISP connection is located in the VLAN 200 building.

I have been given a lot of conflicting information between tagged and untagged functions of the VLANs.  Force10 told me to set all ports that are NOT trunk ports to untagged, and trunk ports to tagged.  ProCurves, however, are the opposite, as well as Netgear switches.  Having the ports set as untagged for the host connections and tagged for the trunk ports works, but should I switch that setup? Or is Force10 just backwards?

As far as the Guest VLAN goes, if I go to tag the host ports necessary, I get a "Tagged flag mis-matched gig 0/23" message.  If I try to untag the ports, it tells me it is already untagged on another VLAN, which makes sense.

I also read that the port needs to be in hybrid mode in order to tag multiple VLANs on it.  If I try to put a host port in hybrid mode, it says it can't because it is a layer 2 port.  If I try to put a trunk port in hybrid mode, it says it can't because it is a layer 3 port. That leaves no port mode available to enter hybrid mode.

Is my current setup truly backwards?  And if so, is it causing the issues with trying to tag multiple VLANs on a port and preventing me from entering hybrid mode on any other ports?

Comment: FWIW, I have never configured Force10 devices.  That said, what Force10 is telling you makes the most sense.  Your access ports should be untagged.  Procurves should be the same, i.e, non-trunk ports are untagged and trunk ports are tagged.

Comment: Cisco and Dell PowerConnect switches are the same as the Force10 switches and IMO follow the general standard of untagged access ports and tagged trunk ports.

Comment: I think I will be rebuilding our internal network configuration over spring break in a month and a half or so.  I need to change the firmware on one of our Force10 switches because I can't telnet into it at all, so maybe rebuilding everything will clear up a possible something that may have been misconfigured.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

stead of using the untagged command you have to use the **no tagged** command.

Answer (score -2):

This is what worked for me

do no switchport in the physical interface
put it in hybrid mode
again do a switchport in the physical interface

H2H...